# Find and classify sequential patterns for a distinct group T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need help finding and classifying sequential patterns for each distinct key.

From the data I have, I need to create a new table that contains the key and a pattern identifier that belongs to that key.

From the example below the pattern is as follows:

> Key #1 and #3 have the values 1, 2 and 3. The Key #3 has the values 8,
>   9 and 10. When a distinct pattern exists for a key I.E (1, 2, 3) I
>   need to create an entry on the table for the key # and that specific
>   pattern (1, 2, 3)

Data:

```
key          value
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            8
2            9
2            10
3            1
3            2
3            3
```

Expected Output:

```
key          pattern
1            1
2            2
3            1
```

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4fe39

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([key] int, [value] int)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([key], [value])
VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (2, 8),
  (2, 9),
  (2, 10),
  (3, 1),
  (3, 2),
  (3, 3)
;
```

Comment: Please describe the logic for the "pattern identifier".  It is not obvious.

Comment: Key #1 and #3 have the values 1, 2  and 3. The Key #3 has the values 8, 9 and 10.  When a distinct pattern exists I.E (1, 2, 3) I need to create an entry on the table for the key # and that specific pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the values together in several ways.  The traditional method in SQL Server uses `for xml`:

```
select k.key,
       stuff( (select ',' + cast(t.id as varchar(255))
               from t
               where k.key = t.key
               for xml path ('')
               order by t.id
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as ids
from (select distinct key from t) k;
```

You can convert this to a unique number using a CTE/subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select k.key,
             stuff( (select ',' + cast(t.id as varchar(255))
                     from t
                     where k.key = t.key
                     for xml path ('')
                     order by t.id
                    ), 1, 1, ''
                  ) as ids
      from (select distinct key from t) k
     )
select cte.*, dense_rank() over (order by ids) as ids_id
from cte;
```

Comment: Your CTE/subquery is the solution but it did not work on my fiddle initially.  
The following fiddle link contains the working solution, thanks for the help!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fb6e/17